# Appium will not start

Tags: android, appium

I changed my configuration to try and run two appium sessions at a time, that way I could inspect and also run automation on a parallel port. Somehow, I broke the avd startup on the appium inspector. I have tried to revert everything back, killall sessions, stop all command line instances of appium, but the problem persists.

full error message:

> error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: You must
>   pass in either the 'app' or 'browserName' cap
>
> info: [debug] Error: You must pass in either the 'app' or
>   'browserName' cap
>       at e (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/capabilities.js:171:34)
>       at [object Object].Capabilities.checkStrictValidity (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/capabilities.js:188:12)
>       at [object Object].Capabilities.checkValidity (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/capabilities.js:140:10)
>       at [object Object].Appium.configure (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:238:35)
>       at [object Object]. (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:118:10)
>       at [object Object].Appium.start (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js:129:5)
>       at exports.createSession (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/controller.js:188:16)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:100:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/server/controller.js:39:7
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:10
>   4:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:104:14)
>       at Route.dispatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
>       at Function.proto.process_params (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
>       at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
>       at methodOverride (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/method-override/index.js:79:5)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
>       at trim_prefix (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
>       at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
>   info: [debug] Responding to client with error:
>   {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: You must pass in either the 'app' or 'browserName'
>   cap)","origValue":"You must pass in either the 'app' or 'browserName'
>   cap"},"sessionId":null} info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 5.350 ms -
>   230
>
> info: --> GET /wd/hub/status {}
>
> info: [debug] Responding to client with success:
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}
>   info: <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 0.664 ms - 105
>   {"status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"1.4.13","revision":"c75d8adcb66a75818a542fe1891a34260c21f76a"}}}

screeshot of alert:
[image]

settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if more information is required. Thank you.

Comment: hm the error is a missing app/browserName but I see you have app set. However I also see you don't have deviceName set which is required. Try setting that and let me know what happens.

Comment: I took it off to see if it would resolve the issue. Added it back up and getting the same error.

Comment: Does appium has access to appPath you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please check(tick) the following options :

```
Android Settings -> Basic -> Package [possible cause of failure]
Android Settings -> Advanced -> SDK
```

By the way this would be just in case you want to run your application using the UI capabilities(maybe using Appium inspector standalone), otherwise if you are using some `client` to setup the `capabilities` it would be great to see the code for your setup to suggest any required changes.

Answer (score 0):

app package and activity name missing . Need to add package and activity name into desiredcapabilities

Answer (score 0):

Update your appium desktop to the latest version. Currently i am using 1.8.1 version.

Steps:

1. Start appium Desktop
2. Click on Advance tab
3. Enter server address=127.0.0.1, port=4723, check **Allow Session Override** checkbox
4. Click Start Server button. It will start appium server
5. Click on **eye glass icon** in top right corner of appium desktop app. A new window will appear.
6. In appear window, you will see desired capabilities menu. You need to insert following parameters.

   - deviceName
   - platformName
   - appPackage
   - appActivity

[image: Appium desktop desired capabilites]

7. Click on Start Session button

> Make sure your device to is connected to your computer and usb debugging is enable in your device.